# Bring variable value from Block to use in Global Scope - JAVASCRIPT (in FIRESTORE)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, scope, google-cloud-functions, global-variables

I'm creating an App in Firebase, using FireStore as my Database.

In the code below, I create a variable `order` and assign it a value of 1.

Then I update the value to the number 4 and `console.log` it to check. Which turns out fine.

But when I log the variable after the function, to cross-check, it returns 1 again, instead of the updated value(i.e. 4).

> **I want to use the value I'm getting from the database, in the global**
>   **namespace. (use it simply in my JS code outside this function.)**

**This is My code** (do See the  //comments)

```js
    console.log("Value initiated : " + order); // logs 'Value initiated : 1'

    //A function that gets another value from the FireStore Database and assigns it to the variable.
    function getField() {
      db.collection("index")
        .doc("artNum")
        .get()
        .then(function(doc) {
          order = doc.data().artNum; //I reassign the variable to '4' here.
          console.log("Value assigned : " + order); // logs 'Value assigned : 4'
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

    getField(); 
    console.log("Updated Value : " + order); // (to crosscheck) logs " Updated Value : 1 " but should be equal to 4
```

I've been into JS for only a month, I'm quite a beginner. Some of the solutions I thought-&-tried were.

1. Use `order` variable outside the function straight-away, like I did above, which didn't work.
2. Assign the value of `order` to a new variable in the global namespace, which didn't work either.

**I want to use this value outside in my global namespace.**

> Please help me with what I'm doing wrong or what this code is missing.

Comment: In short - don't. Put all the functionality that depends on the asynchronous info *inside* the `.then` instead (eg, call a function that processes the result)

Comment: Basically, I want to use the `order` variable outside, in my code. Also, I'll use this variable again, for naming other documents in my Firestore Database. In simple terms, It's necessary for me to have this value as a simple `var` variable in my script.

@CertainPerformance

Comment: You can't, at least not in any good way. See the linked questions.